# phpseclib fails more than succeeds - php script

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

Recently had to change from FTP to SFTP to upload some data files to 2 remote servers.
Files are typically 1 - 4 Mb in size

I am getting errors ( fails to upload ) around 50% of the attempts.
This is happening to both servers that I am uploading to ( so not 1 server only ).
This is over multiple days of running the php script.

If I manually connect to the servers using Filezilla ( from my laptop, on same LAN as the Pi running the php script ), I can connect and upload without errors every time.

The fact that some uploads work, seems to indicate that the code does not contain any errors.

The Filezilla connection does seem a lot slower than a normal FTP connection, both for the login and the directory listing.

I am guessing that Filezilla has a better retry / timeout procedure than the phpseclib ?

Are there features / code in phpseclib that will make it more reliable under these conditions ?

Code and errors listed below ( IP and username changed ).

```
<?php

    $CodeRoot = dirname(__FILE__);
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $CodeRoot.'/phpseclib');
    include($CodeRoot.'/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');

    $RetryCount = 0;
    $MaxRetryCount = 3;
    do {  // repeat loop for 3 times unless upload OK and file sizes match

        $RetryCount = $RetryCount + 1;
        echoline("----- Upload Attempt  # ".$RetryCount."  to: $ftpServer");
        /// note : the 'echoline' code simply writes the message to a date specific text/log file and mails it back to me at the end

            $ftp_conn11 = new NET_SFTP($ftpServer);
            if ($ftp_conn11){
                $ftp_login = $ftp_conn11->login($ftpUser, $ftpPassword);
                if (!$ftp_login) {
                    echoline("Login Failed");
                }
                if ($ftp_login){
                    if($ftp_conn11->put($remote_file, $local_file, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE)){
                        echoline("----- File uploaded successfully to: $ftpServer");
                        $remoteSize = $ftp_conn11->size($remote_file);
                        $localSize = filesize($local_file);
                        if ($remoteSize == $localSize){
                            echoline("ALL OK ----- The FTP file size and LOCAL file sizes match");
                            $RetryCount = $MaxRetryCount + 2; // break out of the 3x retry loop
                        }
                        if ($remoteSize != $localSize){
                            echoline("ERROR ----- The FTP file size and LOCAL file size does not match");
                        }
                    } else {
                        $msg = "Cannot upload to ftp $ftpServer, Using user $ftpUser";
                        echoline($msg);
                    }
                }else{
                    $msg = "Cannot login to FTP server: $ftpServer using user $ftpUser";
                    echoline($msg);
                }
            }else{
                $msg = "Cannot connect to FTP server: $ftpServer";
                echoline($msg);
            }  // end of : if ($ftp_conn11)
            $ftp_conn11->disconnect();
        sleep(3);
    } while ($RetryCount <= $MaxRetryCount);
    echoline("---------------------------------------------------------------");
?>
```

/// note : the 'echoline' code simply writes the message to a text file and mails it back to me at the end

18:00:11 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 1  to: $TargetServer_1
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2587

Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2587
18:00:36 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_1, Using user $userName
18:00:39 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

18:00:39 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 2  to: $TargetServer_1
18:01:06 --- ----- File uploaded successfully to: $TargetServer_1
18:01:07 --- ALL OK ----- The FTP file size and LOCAL file sizes match
18:01:10 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:20:22 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 1  to: $TargetServer_2
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553

Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553
19:20:52 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_2, Using user $userName
19:20:55 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:20:55 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 2  to: $TargetServer_2
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_HANDLE or SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2400

Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_HANDLE or SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2400
19:21:13 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_2, Using user $userName
19:21:16 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:21:16 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 3  to: $TargetServer_2
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553

Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553
19:21:43 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_2, Using user $userName
19:21:46 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:21:46 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 4  to: $TargetServer_2
Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_HANDLE or SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2400
19:22:04 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_2, Using user $userName
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_HANDLE or SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2400
19:22:07 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

18:00:32 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 1  to: $TargetServer_2
18:00:50 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_2, Using user $userName
18:00:53 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

18:00:53 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 2  to: $TargetServer_2
18:01:03 --- Login Failed
18:01:03 --- Cannot login to FTP server: $TargetServer_2 using user $userName
18:01:07 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

18:01:07 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 3  to: $TargetServer_2
18:01:23 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_2, Using user $userName
18:01:26 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

18:01:26 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 4  to: $TargetServer_2
18:01:43 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_2, Using user $userName
18:01:46 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:20:10 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 1  to: $TargetServer_1
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553

Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553
19:20:47 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_1, Using user $userName
19:20:50 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:20:50 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 2  to: $TargetServer_1
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_HANDLE or SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2400

Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_HANDLE or SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2400
19:21:06 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_1, Using user $userName
19:21:09 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:21:09 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 3  to: $TargetServer_1
PHP Notice:  Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553

Notice: Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS in /config/www/folder1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 2553
19:21:24 --- Cannot upload to ftp $TargetServer_1, Using user $userName
19:21:27 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

19:21:27 --- ----- Upload Attempt  # 4  to: $TargetServer_1
19:21:43 --- ----- File uploaded successfully to: $TargetServer_1
19:21:43 --- ALL OK ----- The FTP file size and LOCAL file sizes match
19:21:46 --- ---------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: The code line do not seem to match the latest version of phpseclib. Consider upgrading. + Post phpseclib log file.

Comment: SFTP is often slower than SCP because with SFTP you upload files in 32KB chunks and for every chunk you upload you have to wait for a confirmation packet, SSH_FXP_STATUS. Waiting for that packet is what winds up eating a lot of the time. SCP will send data without waiting for that packet. I assume FTP works similarly. To speed things up phpseclib sends up to 1024x 32KB packets and _then_ tries to read up to 1024x SSH_FXP_STATUSes. Like it lets the SSH_FXP_STATUSes queue up instead of reading them after every 32KB packet. PuTTY (which in turn is used by WinSCP) does the same thing.

Comment: So if that's what's going on then the issue should be duplicatable with WinSCP vs FileZilla. And if that's the case then doing  `define('NET_SFTP_UPLOAD_QUEUE_SIZE', 1)` is liable to help. If that does help then you could try scaling that up. Maybe 1x at a time is the most that your SFTP server can do but maybe it can do 32x? Maybe 128x? You'll have to find out through trial and error.

Comment: That said, Martin Prikryl is right - you're using a waaaay old version of phpseclib. You're using phpseclib v1. The latest version is phpseclib is v3. You don't include Net/SFTP.php with v3 - you let composer autoload it. And you don't do `new NET_SFTP($ftpServer);` - you do `new \phpseclib3\Net\SFTP($ftpServer);`. Newer versions of phpseclib don't just tell you what packet it was expecting but didn't get - they also tell you what packet phpseclib got back. That's super useful w.r.t. diagnosing issues and is a data set that we don't have due to your using such an old version.

Comment: Also, Martin Prikryl is right that the log files would help. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top and then `echo $ssh->getLog()` after the error. Like one thing that's liable to tell us is what the SSH server you're connecting to is. If it's something super esoteric then it's possible that the SSH server doesn't support the sending of 1024x 32KB packets at a time. If that's the case a hard-coded exception in behavior could be made for that SSH server based on the server identifier.

Comment: phpseclib hard-coding exceptions in behavior is with precedent as PuTTY / WinSCP do the same thing. Quoting https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.80/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-bugs , "_Since most servers announce their software version number at the beginning of the SSH connection, PuTTY will attempt to detect which bugs it can expect to see in the server and automatically enable workarounds_".

Comment: Thanks all for the input. I think I may have found a solution, which is simply adding a timeout setting to override the default 10 seconds.  `      $ftp_conn21 = new NET_SFTP($ftpServer);
      $ftp_conn21->setTimeout(20);
` seems to make it work

Comment: as far as upgrading to the latest version of phpseclib, I have 2 problems with that :  1 - I have no understanding of what Composer is or how it works, and 2. if it involves using terminal to execute or install, that's out for me. My backup of my script runs on a hosted shared server and I have no access to the settings / installs on the server

Comment: Well phpseclib 1 is still officially supported so using that isn't a problem so long as you're on the latest version! I mean, you're not gonna have support for the latest and greatest encryption algorithms with v1 but v1 still gets bug fixes and periodic new features so long as those new features don't involve a complete redesign of the internals. That said, if you _did_ want to try phpseclib 3.0 you could do so without using Composer _per say_ using the directions at https://phpseclib.com/docs/install#without-composer

Comment: Also, tip for using stackoverflow...  if you're responded to a comment make sure you `@` the person who you're responding to so that they get a notification that you responded. eg. `@neubert - blah blah blah`. Like I didn't know you responded until I just got bored and reloaded the page. I'm not doing `@Dave O'Brien` because you, as the original question asker, get notified of all responses, but neither I or Martin are, so we don't get notifications.

Comment: @neubert Thank You so much for the link - I am going to look at that now. And a big Thanks also for the tip on using the @ to respond - I am very new to stackoverflow soo learning as I go

Comment: @neubert ok. started to read the instructions, but as usual, they assume that the reader has a certain level of understanding before they strt. For example, it says 'The first step will be to create a new directory' - is this in my public_html directory, in the phpseclib directory, etc ?   Then it says 'Then, in your shell, type the following in: composer install' - is this 'shell' the ssh terminal to the root of the web server ?

Comment: Do you even have SSH access to the shared server? If you do then you could do Composer on that but if you don't then that won't be an option, at which point, it could be _any_ directory. Like create C:\neubert as an empty directory.  The public_html directory doesn't have to have to even live in that same hard drive. Then, assuming Composer has been installed using the directions at https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md, you'd type in `composer install` in Power Shell or Command Prompt or whatever